# Xcode can't find a module, after updating

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa

I've recently updated my Xcode, but I faced with strange issue.

I'm installing library via cocoapods and use it further in my project, but after updating I Xcode can't find the module, I've installed via CocoaPods

I've updating pods, but the problem stays. 
Also I have Pods.framework red

What is the problem?

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Bloom' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Bloom

  target 'BloomTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'BloomUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Gifu'
```

UPD: Solved it by opening the project with the .xcworkspace file not with .xcodeproj.

Comment: What frameworks do you use?

Answer (score 13):

Do the following things and you can import any swift file from "Pods"

1. Clean your project
2. Make sure that all your "Pods" > "Build Settings" > "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "NO".
3. Don't run, just build your project.
4. Now, import any file from "Pods" to any swift file

This will solve your `import module` problem.

> Update:

To solve this issue delete the current pod file and create one using the terminal. Follow the below steps:

1) Open Terminal.

2) Navigate to your Project Path.

3) Type `pod init` in terminal to create new pod file.

4) Open the newly created pod file and write the pod line which you want to install after `target "TargetName" do` and before `end`.

5) Then type `pod install` in the terminal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but what do you mean by cleaning project

Comment: @DanielChepenko In Xcode > Click on Product > Tap on Clean

Comment: @DanielChepenko Or you could just tap cmd+shift+k, that would clean it as well

Comment: @SohilR.Menon Ok, I got it, but still have such issue. it occurs only on one concrete module, other are ok

Comment: @DanielChepenko Can I see your pod file?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Oh, still the same mistake

Comment: "Make sure that all your "Pods" > "Build Settings" > "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "NO"." FINALLY solved my issue

Comment: Where is "Pods"?

Comment: Everybody miss important point: if you opened xcode with <proj>.xcodeproj then made "pod install", then you should close xcode and open your project with another file - <proj>.xcworkspace. Now you see pods as separate projects, which has it's build options.

Comment: I found that toggling `Build Active Architecture Only` (either to `YES` or `NO`), cleaning, then rebuilding resolved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had to delete my podfile and ALL the files it made including the .workspace file then I did:

```
pod init
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

add pods I want to podfile then save and close xcode.

Finally do pod install and open the new workspace file :)

Answer (score 2):

change your pod file like this and clean the project quit xcode and reopen it.it may solve the problem

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use       
dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

target 'Bloom' do

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Gifu'
end

target 'BloomTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

target 'BloomUITests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end
```

Comment: didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Some frameworks in cocoapods declare a hard-link to XCode in the module description file (XMPP for example). So, be sure that you have:

- place XCode.app in /Application (default folder), with name
  "XCode.app", not Xcode-beta.app

or/and

- call xcode-select to specify the right XCode.app:

  sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: Problem occurs, while working with Gify https://github.com/kaishin/Gifu

Comment: Try to re-install this pod. Remove Gifu from podfile, do an Pod Update, then add Gifu in podfile, and do again a Pod Update.

Comment: didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I tried to merge a branch using Xcode (never again!). 
What finally worked for me was:

1. Deleting derved data
2. Cleaning project
3. Exiting Xcode
4. Running 'pod install' again in my project